# Handling the HttpWebResponse before throwing exception for (404) File Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, webclient, httpwebresponse

Is there any way to process the `HttpWebResponse.GetResponse()` before throwing exception for  (404) File Not Found?

I have a huge amount of images to download, and using Try..catch to handle the exceptions of file not found will make the performance very bad.

```
private bool Download(string url, string destination)
 {
     try
     {
            if (RemoteFileExists("http://www.example.com/FileNotFound.png")
            {
                   WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
                         downloader.DownloadFile(url, destination);
                         return true;
            }
     }
     catch(WebException webEx)
     {
     }
     return false;
 }

private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
    try
    {
        //Creating the HttpWebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        //Getting the Web Response.
        //Here is my question, When the image's not there, 
//the following line will throw an exception, How to avoid that?
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        //Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Any exception will returns false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), it doesn't throw exception on 404:

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient();

var resp = await c.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, "http://www.google.com/abcde"));

bool ok = resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `HttpClient` by sending `Async` request will solve the exception of (404 file not found), so i will consider it as an answer to this question, However, I would like to share my performance test here. I have tested both of the following methods to download 50,000 images :

Method 1

```
try
{
    // I will not check at all and let the the exception happens
    downloader.DownloadFile(url, destination);
    return true;
}
catch(WebException webEx)
{
}
```

Method 2

```
try
{
    // Using HttpClient to avoid the 404 exception
    HttpClient c = new HttpClient();

    var resp = await c.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head,
            "http://www.example.com/img.jpg"));

    if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        downloader.DownloadFile(url, destination);
        return true;
    }
}
catch(WebException webEx)
{
}
```

In my test, 144 images were not available out of 50.000 images to be downloaded, The performance in Method 1 is 3x Faster than Method 2.